# unix shell sub string?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

I want to extract substring till the point the last numeric ends.

for example:

In the string "abcd123z" , I want the output to be "abcd123"

In the string "abcdef123gh01yz" , I want the output to be "abcdef123gh01"

In the string "abcd123" , I want the output to be "abcd123"

How to do this in the unix shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sed command,

```
sed 's/^\(.*[0-9]\).*$/\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'abcdef123gh01yz' | sed 's/^\(.*[0-9]\).*$/\1/g'
abcdef123gh01
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in BASH regex:

```
str='abcdef123gh01yz'
[[ "$str" =~ ^(.*[[:digit:]]) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
abcdef123gh01
```

Comment: Yes I clearly mentioned `BASH` because of that since OP tagged the question with `BASH`

Comment: He tagged bash *and* ksh

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp="${str##*[0-9]}"     # cut off all up to last digit, keep intermediate
echo "${str%$tmp}"        #  remove intermediate from end of string
```